# Post request with encrypted json data with several keys and one image file() multipart , android

Tags: retrofit2

Have to pass this json to server, and encrypted param will be created after creating the json and it will return the same json with three parameters, but I am not able to do it with image or file data.

After encrypting the data these params(param1, param2, param3) automatically get created

I tried using @PartMap using Map, @Part @Multipart

```
{
"fullname": "hello",
"dob": "20-12-1992",
  "locale":{
  "language: "en",
  "version": 2,
 },
 "media": {
 "media":{
  "name:"",
  "size":""
  }
 },
 "param1":"",
 "param2":"",
 "param3":""
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2760 , see the issue , i have to pass a Encrypted JSONObject and a file , using multipart retrofit

Comment: POST(ConstantValues.UPDATE_PROFILE)
    Call<ResponseBody> updateProfile(
            Header("Authorization") String token,
            Part MultipartBody.Part file ,
            Part RequestBody body)

Comment: i tried it using @PartMap , but getting error map validation invalid , and for creating map i am doing a recursion process , which is unnecessarily i have to do , because our encryption library only accept json string, and using part it is asking a key which send the value inside that key